# Convert "Mon, 01 Apr 2013 10:00:00 GMT" into datetime in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to convert this string "Mon, 01 Apr 2013 10:00:00 GMT" into datetime in sql server 2008
but due to GMT I am unable to convert it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do:

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(30)
SET @Date = 'Mon, 01 Apr 2013 10:00:00 GMT'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(@Date,5,21),113)
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the edit. I was using `@Date` when I tried it, and forgot to change one of them on my answer